# push notification with images in React native

Tags: react-native, push-notification

Using [zo0r/react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/) can we show images(big images/small images) received as part of push messages?

Something like this ?

[Sample Push Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYEEw.jpg)

Comment: Anyone, update?

Comment: Hey did you find a solution for this? Either using this or with some other library, would be helpful .